# Want to add an indicator when a button is focused

Tags: android

I am currently developing an android TV app and have configured a basic button on the main fragment. At the current time there is no way of indicating wether you are focusing on, or knowing you can click on this button. I created a view with a drawable background, to use as the indicator; then wrote some code (Kotlin). At first I wrote: `indicator.isVisible=button.isFocused` to no avail, I also tried earlier in the code to set (as a test) `button.isFocused = true` this also did not work. After, some research I realised that you could set the button to focused by default. After inserting this into the code, there was of course an issue with the API usage (26 or above); mine being API 22. So, I'd like to know for an API below 26 (in my case 22) how can I make the indicator visible when the button is focused? Once again, so the user knows what they're currently hovering over (especially in rows with many selectable views)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Well, looking at the View documentation, I found out there is a ***setOnHoverListener*** method and a *OnHoverListener* interface. I haven't tried it but I think this one is what you are looking for.

**Old answer:**

You can create a new xml drawable with different background colors for each state (hover, pressed, default) and set that drawable as the button's background.

The new drawable would look like this, i.e :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/gold" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

Comment: The view of the indicator is seperate. Correnct me if I'm wrong but this would only change the buttons characteristics, not change the visibility of a seperate object

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I didn't get that at first. I think you can ***setOnFocusChangeListener*** on a Button(View). That should be it!

Comment: I'll give it a try and comment with the result

Comment: That did not seem to work.